# How to shorthand imports of Models in PHP Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I tried short handling my models in my controller since they are in the same folder. So Instead of doing these:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use App\Pictures;
use App\Info;
```

I tried these:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\{ 
    User, Pictures, Info
};
```

Unfortunately it's not working. It shows that the controller doesn't read it when I short handed it. Any suggestions or reasons why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are you on php 7+?

Comment: @devk I'm actually using php 7.2

Comment: Could you elaborate on `it is not working`? What exactly does it say?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort , by that I meant the shorthanding does not work. Which means, php 7.2 of mine, doesn't read it by shorthand code. use App\{ 
    User, Pictures, Info
};

Comment: Yes i get that ;) I meant what is the error you get, is it a syntax error, class not found or something else?

Answer (score -1):

In PHP V7.0, You can refer this method http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

```
<?php

// Pre PHP 7 code
use some\namespace\ClassA;
use some\namespace\ClassB;
use some\namespace\ClassC as C;

use function some\namespace\fn_a;
use function some\namespace\fn_b;
use function some\namespace\fn_c;

use const some\namespace\ConstA;
use const some\namespace\ConstB;
use const some\namespace\ConstC;

// PHP 7+ code
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
use function some\namespace\{fn_a, fn_b, fn_c};
use const some\namespace\{ConstA, ConstB, ConstC};
```

Comment: You are doing exactly the same thing as the OP, only in a different format

Comment: Are you expecting something beyond the programming language ?